# Error on Rss Feed for my blog

Tags: rss, feed

I searched on this website but didnt get any proper solution for my problem.

I got this website : http://www.droidacid.com/feed/

I am not able to get the Rss feed or xml file of my website.
Actually I need to develop an Android application for my website and need my xml link for the same.

Hope to receive some answers soon or link to a similar problem(I searched but did not get similar problem).

Thanks

Comment: "I am not able to get the Rss feed or xml file of my website" - can you be more specific about what the problem is please? That link returns an RSS feed for me, and [feedvalidator says it's OK](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.droidacid.com%2Ffeed%2F) barring one warning. Is it a server side error you're seeing in the logs, or content you're expecting is missing, or something else?

Comment: Yeah there were some post issues with invalid chars...delete that post and it started working...